# How much currency, on average, to expect from Bitcoin mining?

Tags: mining-profitability, difficulty, mining-setup

As mining difficulty continues to rise, I don't know if it is even worth trying.

My question to the users actively mining is, how many Bitcoins, on average, are most miners making? And any recent numbers you are willing to share from your mining operations would be appreciated, too.

This question may be impossible to answer without knowing what hardware and software most miners are using. So I ask a secondary question: what are the dominant hardware and software configurations used by the current players in the mining game?

Finally, who are the most successful miners, how many Bitcoins are they mining, and are they mining with incredibly advanced and expensive mining hardware?

Comment: Because of efficiency of scale and markets, you'd probably be better of just buying shares of hashing power at an exchange like cex.io. (That is assuming you're most interested in profits and the mining experience is of little relative value to you.)

Comment: @Tyler With recent happenings, it is imperative to ensure that cloud mining companies are not scams, and actually have hashing power (as opposed to acting as a pyramid scheme).